# Inserir Sumario em documento Word utilizando biblioteca apache poi

Tags: android, android-studio, apache, apache-poi

Estou criando um aplicativo android de resposta de formulários, ao final do questionário estou criando um arquivo .docx utilizando a biblioteca apache poi, o documento ja é escrito com sucesso, porem gostaria de adicionar um Sumario, eu pesquisei mas porem não encontrei o que eu precisava, gostaria de saber se é possível?